# Bootstrap with jQuery - Delete this button's parent with Modal confirmation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap.

I have 4 different boxes with same class with delete link inside it.

If I click on Delete link, it should open confirmation Modal dialog with message, and by confirming it should delete the parent box of clicked element.

I can able to delete only this Link not parent. (Thanks to Bootply :) )

> **[Online Demo](http://www.bootply.com/qndZ0KmkRL)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"><h1>Heading 1</h1><a href="#" class="confirm-delete" data-id="1">Delete</a></div>
  <div class="box"><h1>Heading 2</h1><a href="#" class="confirm-delete" data-id="2">Delete</a></div>
  <div class="box"><h1>Heading 3</h1><a href="#" class="confirm-delete" data-id="3">Delete</a></div>
  <div class="box"><h1>Heading 4</h1><a href="#" class="confirm-delete" data-id="4">Delete</a></div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal hide">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="close">×</a>
    <h3>Delete</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>You are about to delete.</p>
    <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" id="btnYes" class="btn danger">Yes</a>
    <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="btn secondary">No</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#myModal').on('show', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id'),
        removeBtn = $(this).find('.danger');
})

$('.confirm-delete').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#myModal').data('id', id).modal('show');
});

$('#btnYes').click(function() {
    // handle deletion here
    var id = $('#myModal').data('id');
    $('[data-id='+id+']').remove();
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you want to delete the parent, you just need to use jQuery's `.parent()` function. So, change your delete line to

```
$('[data-id='+id+']').parent().remove();
```

and that should do the trick.

Here's a demo: http://www.bootply.com/Bz1u80HCrO

Comment: You beat me to it by 50 seconds :)

Comment: @TobiasBeuving And it looks like I was beaten to it too. :P

Comment: If only all questions could be answered as smooth as this! ;)

Comment: Thanks **@BurningLights**... I am voting up your answer and Accepting... Thanks for **Quickie** :)

Answer (score 3):

You should try it :

```
$('[data-id='+id+']').parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery's parent() function](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) for that:

```
$('[data-id='+id+']').remove();
```

will be:

```
$('[data-id='+id+']').parent().remove();
```